Is there a bin or junk folder for deleted discount codes I can restore from?
I've deleted a discount code rather than inactivated it, and need to know if there is anyway to retrieve it so that I can search for it in a SearchKit report? Is there a way to do this, or would there be a record of the code left in 'contributions' anyway? I've had a manual look through old events and can't find many discounted event registrations except under another code anyway, so it's possible this code was never used.

If you have logging on then there should be a table in the db for log_civicrm_discount. however there seem to be other discount tables eg cividiscount_item and cividiscount_track which do not have log tables (at least not on the instance I am looking at). not sure if that is helpful but if some of the data you were looking for would have been in the civicrm_discount table then in theory you could do an sql insert from the log table for the deleted row
